# Where are the actual names of the packages in "apt list --upgradable"?

Tags: apt

It seems to be printing only the versions:

```
$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
dpkg/bionic-updates 1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.19.0.5ubuntu2.2]
file-roller/bionic-security 3.28.0-1ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.28.0-1ubuntu1]
libdpkg-perl/bionic-updates,bionic-updates 1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3 all [upgradable from: 1.19.0.5ubuntu2.2]
```

Tried using "`1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3`" or just "`ubuntu`", to no avail as expected:

```
$ apt show 1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3
N: Unable to locate package 1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3
N: Couldn't find any package by glob '1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3'
N: Couldn't find any package by regex '1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3'
N: Unable to locate package 1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3
N: Couldn't find any package by glob '1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3'
N: Couldn't find any package by regex '1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3'
E: No packages found
$ apt show ubuntu
N: Unable to locate package ubuntu
N: Unable to locate package ubuntu
E: No packages found
```

So, where are the actual package names? OS version reads Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Comment: The package names precede the /

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dpkg`, `file-roller`, and `libdpkg-perl` are the packages that can be upgraded. `1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3`, `3.28.0-1ubuntu1.1`, and `1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3` are the versions to which they can be upgraded, respectively.

Comment: Oops. I thought these are parts of repository names. Remarkably counterintuitive format, but I guess it's historical. Thanks.